# Cannot set readonly property: class for class in groovy when initializing with map

Tags: groovy

I am trying to create a class and initialize all the values with a default value. So i have this pojo in groovy, and i have created initializeWithDefaults method to initialize all the values. I am trying to pass map in the constructor

```
class MDS {
    String id
    String mdsName
    String name
    String mdsType
    String mdsContext
    String mdsDateTime
    String mdsDomain

    public static void initializeWithDefaults() {
        MDS dataSegmentIdDef = new MDS()
        Map<String, Object> prop = dataSegmentIdDef.properties
        prop.each { Map.Entry entry->
            entry.value = "default-${entry.key}"
        }

        MDS dataSegmentId = new MDS(prop)

    }
}
```

but i keep getting the error

```
in thread "main" groovy.lang.ReadOnlyPropertyException: Cannot set readonly property: class for class: com.ambuj.domain.MDS
```

Comment: Why not just skip the 'class' property? `if (entry.key != 'class') entry.value = "default-${entry.key}"`

Comment: yeah ended up doing that only, was thinking of way to avoid this or may be there is some better way on what i am trying to achieve there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error, as you are trying to override a `class` propery of a `*HashMap` which is provided as a `getClass()` and of course not writeable.

You should take care, what properties you are trying to copy. A simple experiment in Groovy console looked like (pay attention to `!prop.synthetic`):

```
class MDS {
  // your props

  @Override
  String toString() {
    "$id:$mdsName:$mdsDomain"
  }

  static void initializeWithDefaults() {
    MDS mds = MDS.class.declaredFields.inject( new MDS() ){ MDS mds, prop ->
      if( !prop.synthetic ) mds[ prop.name ] = "default.$prop.name"
      mds
    }
    println mds
  }
}

MDS.initializeWithDefaults()
```

and the output:

```
Result: default.id:default.mdsName:default.mdsDomain
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick fix is to filter out the properties that already have a value using the `findAll` method.

```
public static void initializeWithDefaults() {
    MDS dataSegmentIdDef = new MDS()
    Map<String, Object> prop = dataSegmentIdDef.properties.findAll { !it.value }
    prop.each { Map.Entry entry->
        entry.value = "default-${entry.key}"
    }

    MDS dataSegmentId = new MDS(prop)
}
```

I'd also recommend replacing the `each` with a `collectEntries`

```
    Map<String, Object> prop = dataSegmentIdDef.properties
            .findAll { !it.value }
            .collectEntries { key, noValue -> [key, "default-$key"] }
```